# Splice function isn't working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, splice

here is my issue.
I'm trying to remove an object from an array, but the splice function seems to provoc crash.

```
$http({
   method : "POST",
   url : "getDatesBasket",
   data:   {"mission":pos_id},
   async:false
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    var rep = response['data'];
    var repSplit = rep.split(",");
    var posSplit = repSplit[0];
    var posTemp = posSplit.split(":")[1];
    for (kPos = 0; kPos < $scope.datePos.length; kPos++) {
        alert("BEFORE " +$scope.datePos[kPos].dateMax);
        if(posTemp==$scope.datePos[kPos].pos){
            alert('start suppression');
            datePos.splice(kpos,1);
            alert('end suppression');
        }
        alert("AFTER " +$scope.datePos[kPos].dateMax);
    }
```

when running this I see the alert boxes `BEFORE` and `start suppression`
but not `end suppression`, it's like the splice function made the code crash.

EDIT

Here is datePos, it's an array with object built like that
I perform an ajax request to get some data, then i push those data inside the tab. So this is an object with two key, pos and data

```
  $http({
       method: "POST",
       url: "getDatesBasket",
       data: {
           "mission": pos_id
       },
       async: false
   }).then(function successCallback(response) {
           var rep = response['data'];
           var repSplit = rep.split(",");
           var posSplit = repSplit[0];
           var dateSplit = repSplit[1];
           var posTemp = posSplit.split(":")[1];
           var date = dateSplit.split(":")[1];
           var myPos = {
               pos: posTemp,
               dateMax: date
           };
           $scope.datePos.push(myPos);
```

Comment: If you are not seeing the `start suppression` alert then your `if` condition is not evaluating to `true`  Check the console to see any errors.

Comment: What could possibly go wrong when you're changing the array you're currently iterating over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to splice the same array which is defined on your scope.And also you are using lowercase letter inside your splice.It should be `kPos` .So you have to splice like this.

```
$scope.datePos.splice(kPos,1);
```

Comment: In fact i just tested it, and it's still not working.

Comment: What is $scope.datePos? Can you post the code for ths variable?

Comment: I add it in the first post

Comment: When the alert happens, do you the scope value $scope.datePos[kPos].dateMax alert("BEFORE " +$scope.datePos[kPos].dateMax);

Comment: And your posTemp is not defined on scope in your js and you are referencing it in your view?

Comment: No, posTemp isn't in view, i just use it to save the response data. Nothing in the posDate array is print later.

Comment: In fact, the value, rep - repSplit ....posTemp that you can see  where i push the data are also just above the for. This for where i'm trying is inside the success case of an ajax request getting the removed data. So posTemp is well defined. And i go inside the if because i print "start suppression"

Comment: Ohh my bad, You are correct. I think the variable is small case inside splice datePos.splice(kpos,1) where kpos is kPos  in for loop

Comment: Holy **** you must be right....i didn't see that at all, it must be that. Pretty sure i think, i let you know later if this is working.

Comment: I works fine now, thanks. I'm going to change my glasses^^

Comment: Lol, Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you forget to use **$scope**.
Here is updated code..

```
for (kPos = 0; kPos < $scope.datePos.length; kPos++) {
    alert("BEFORE " +$scope.datePos[kPos].dateMax);
    if(posTemp==$scope.datePos[kPos].pos){
        alert('start suppression');
        $scope.datePos.splice(kpos,1);
        alert('end suppression');
    }
    alert("AFTER " +$scope.datePos[kPos].dateMax);
}
```

Comment: In fact i just tested it, and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
for (kPos = $scope.datePos.length-1; kPos>=0; kPos--) {
alert("BEFORE " +$scope.datePos[kPos].dateMax);
if(posTemp==$scope.datePos[kPos].pos){
    alert('start suppression');
    $scope.datePos.splice(kpos,1);
    alert('end suppression');
}
alert("AFTER " +$scope.datePos[kPos].dateMax);
}
```

try it like above.